# how to execute stored procedure through node js

Tags: node.js, procedure

I am using db-oracle module (node.js) to query the tables (SEARCH command). I am able to fetch the records successfully.

I need to execute the stored procedure. Any idea how to execute a oracle stored procedure from node js code ? 
Can i execute through db-oracle module ? Or anyother module is available ?

Note: The stored procedure returns multiple values, I need to capture that too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call that procedure from the `.query` method, like:

```
var oracle = require('db-oracle');
new oracle.Database({
    hostname: 'localhost', user: 'root',
    password: 'password', database: 'node'
}).connect(function(error) {
    if (error) { return console.log("CONNECTION ERROR: " + error); }
    this.query("BEGIN SOME_PROC(); END;").execute(function(error, rows) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
        }
        /* Do something with rows here */
    });
});
```